# Do I have to use `configparser` to create and import a config?

Tags: python, import, config

I tried to simply create a file `config.py` and add some variables to it. In my `main.py` I did:

```
 ...
 import config.py

 print(config_var)
```

but it throws an error:

```
print(config_var)
NameError: name 'config_var' is not defined
```

So I take it that this is not the way to do it in Python?

Comment: What's in your config.py? The python code or environment variables? Try `from config import *; print(locals())`

Comment: first: `import config` without `.py`. Second: if you use `import config` then you need `config.config_var`. If you want directly `config_var` then you need `from config import config_var` or `from config import *`